# How do you do a mxmlc.exe compilation to *.exe and *.app?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have to create an ActionScript 3 project in Flash Builder, and compile with mxmlc.exe, but the output has to be a .exe file for Windows, and also, an .app Macintosh Projector file for Mac.

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what we did, compiled the SWF using mxmlc.exe, then opened the files in Flash Player on Mac and PC respectively, and clicked Create Projector on the menu.

Works a charm!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about an automated way to achieve this, but you can create you exe/app by opening the swf in the standalone flash player and choosing File > Create Projector...

Comment: Thanks, that helps, I just need to test on Mac to see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use Adobe AIR to make an air app that would be "installable" on Win / Mac and even Linux